# Why my network crashes?

Tags: database, ms-access, networking, vb6

In our college, we are conducting a contest, which is in the form of Multiple choice questions.
For that we are using VB as a front-end , MS Access as a back-end.

Ref:[image: Topology we have used.]

The Application VB 6 runs with no problem and the participant entry is added into the database along with their scores, when 1 or 2 clients access the database simultaneously.

Problem:
   But when more than 2 clients access the database simultaneously, the Application crashes.

1.In some clients, we are getting runtimeerror printing some large negative value with a
     message  "Operations query cannot modify the database".

2.In some clients, the VB 6.0 crashes and closes suddenly.

> These errors occurs when we are tried to access the database using
>   OK,SUBMIT buttons.

Could you tell me why this error occurs and how can I correct it.

My Questions are..

1.Is giving the burden of all clients to a single laptop is the problem here?If there is some other problem please explain it.

2.Why I am getting the error as "Operation query cannot modify database", If so then how it works when 1 or 2 clients access the database simultaneously.

Comment: That is possibly the worst network diagram I've ever seen.  You seem to be implying that each client passes its information onto a different client, and one of them eventually talks to the database.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin Could you explain how it will be a task for database. And could you suggest some diagrams or connections.But In our Lab , they used ring topology for all systems, thats why we simply connected a  cable to our laptop, without making many changes in our lab.

Comment: You know why people refer to the internet as "the cloud"? It's because in standard network diagrams, when you don't want to show each connection to each other computers, you show the connections all going through a cloud.  A line from one thing to another indicates a connection just from that one thing to that other thing, and that's not what's going on in your situation.

Comment: Also, you're not asking why the *network* is crashing.  It's not.  It's your application.  I'm willing to bet that everything else on the network, including probably Access, continues to run just fine before and after your app.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin Sorry,I could understand what you said about cloud.But I couldn't get you at last line.could you explain it again.

Comment: If you draw a line from one machine to another in a network diagram, you are implying that that is how the data flows.  You've drawn a line from clients to other clients, not from clients to the server, or from clients to a backbone to the server.  That implies that the data goes from one client to another client to another client until it reaches the server.  It's extremely unlikely that is the actual structure of your network.

Comment: Access isn't running anywhere on any of the PCs in the diagram. Only the Jet/ACE database engine is involved here, and it's running on each of the client workstations, not on the server.

Comment: What are the permissions on the share where the database is stored? It sounds to me like you've just not given proper permissions to the EVERYONE group (the easiest is to give full control to the group).

Answer (score 2):

Access databases (and other directly file-based DBs) are not really built for multi-access.  There are some facilities in place to help it work, but in my experience, it is quite unreliable.

You need a database server running, which can allow multiple clients to the same database simultaneously.  A free option is [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).  There is also a [free version of Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) available.

Comment: Access can readily use a server-based backend of SQL server too.

Comment: That's correct, but I assumed he was simply sharing an Access DB file.  Did I read that wrong?

Comment: No I think I did. I can't imagine using Access unless you needed the User Interface.

Comment: @Brad you are not wrong. We are simply sharing the Access file. And could you explain what is server-based backend of SQL server

Comment: @Brad "You need a database server running" that means do I have to buy a database server with higher configurations?

Comment: Personally, this would be the route I would go - set one machine up to host SQL Server Express, then design the front-end client to simply link to the tables they need.  If you are only dealing with a handful of machines - you'd have no serious performance hit, even on the machine hosting the SQL Server.  You'd have better reliability that way as well, as under the current network diagram - if you lose the machine with direct access to the machine hosting the MDB data source, it's all over for all of the other clients.

Comment: @Comrad_Durandai I could not understand the last line you said. Could you explain it again. And your are suggesting to buy a new host machine.

Comment: The assertion that "Access databases .... are not really built for multi-access" is COMPLETELY FALSE. The Jet/ACE database engine was built for multi-user access from the ground up.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, read the next sentence.  "There are some facilities in place to help it work, but in my experience, it is quite unreliable."  Then, show me a shared Jet DB file in use by more than 5 or so clients at once that actually works.  Clearly he is having trouble with this configuration.  Yes, it *should* work, but don't be so quick to assume that it isn't problematic, by its very nature.

Comment: Without wishing to start a flame war here, at my last job we had 5 or 6 access databases with a concurrent usage of about 15-25 users and they all ran fine. Now I’m sure you have seen badly designed access databases crash and burn with only 5 users but that is not the tool’s fault. A number of factors have to be right to get good multiuser performance out of JET/Access with good DB design being one of them

Comment: @Kevin, agreed, but I think we can also agree that for every good database functioning in this configuration, there are probably 10 others that don't.  I apologize if I have come off as absolute... that wasn't my intention.  I have become frustrated over the years cleaning up poorly-planned Access databases, and judging by the quality of EAGER_STUDENT's question, I get the impression that he would be better off using something server-based to avoid the problem entirely.  (He *is* having this problem after all).  That's just my opinion though.  You are welcome to disagree.

Comment: I have a whole bunch of clients who have Access databases that have been in production use with multiple users for years and years (some for over a decade) and they are quite reliable. Nobody is losing data. Nobody is having multiuser problems. I can only conclude that some people don't know what they are doing when they deploy Access databases, which then leads to people like you, @Brad, claiming the flaw is in Access and not mere pilot error by people who don't know what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

"Operation query cannot modify database"

Badly designed Access databases can have issues with users trying to modify records if they don't have defined Primary keys. This is especially true when multiple people are accessing because it literally can't tell which record to modify if two people try to do the same thing.  Sometimes it will let you insert but not update.

Further if you are looking for performance, Access is just the wrong tool. It has very little in the way of performance tuning options or abilities. SQl Server Express or mySQl would have more things available to diagnose and fix a performance issue.

Comment: "Sometimes it will let you insert but not update." But, here we are inserting new records only and we never update any record. Further, we have a primary key "participant ID"

Comment: How are you getting the PK, is it autogenerated or not? You could have race conditions if it is not autogenerated.

Comment: yes, in our case we are generating the primary key. Say, A user enters the name,phoneno,collegename. thats it. we add that record along with the next participant Id, the user doesnot know any information about the participant ID.The Participant Id, is for only our purpose and not for user.

Comment: Jet/ACE databases can outperform server databases in some contexts because of the lower overhead.

Comment: You don't specify how you get "the next participant id".  If two clients can access the database at the same time and get the same id, then one of them will crash and burn while doing an insert.  You need to do some sort of locking, either in the db or in the server code, to make sure you're not serving up the same id twice.